# python pymssql Why connect to mssql execution error

Tags: python, pymssql

```
#coding = utf8
__author__ = 'Administrator'
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(host="211.1.1.1",user="hqyl", password = "ttt", database = "ticket")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(%d, xinos.king)", \
    [ (1, 'John Doe'), (2, 'Jane Doe') ])
conn.commit()  # you must call commit() to persist your data if you don't set autocommit to True

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep=xinos.king', 'John Doe')
row = cur.fetchone()
while row:
    print "ID=%d, Name=xinos.king" % (row[0], row[1])
    row = cur.fetchone()

# if you call execute() with one argument, you can use % sign as usual
# (it loses its special meaning).
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE salesrep LIKE 'J%'")

conn.close()
```

The following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/python/t.py", line 7, in <module>
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE persons(id INT, name VARCHAR(100))')
  File "pymssql.pyx", line 411, in pymssql.Cursor.execute (pymssql.c:5634)
pymssql.OperationalError: (262, "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'Ticket'. DB-Lib error message 262, severity 14:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")
```

Comment: Did you check your sql server logs? You should include them if they pertain pertinent information... Just a hunch, but judging from `SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server` in the error, that might answer your question.

Comment: User hqyl does not have permissions to create new tables in the database. Log in to the Ticket database as administrator and grant permissions to create tables to user hqyl i.e. `GRANT CREATE TABLE TO hqyl;`